# Use property getter method reference for functional (SAM) interface variables

Tags: java, kotlin, method-reference, functional-interface

I want to pass a property getter method reference as one of the function arguments, and have that argument be of my own functional interface type, but ran into an issue.

Here's a stripped down minimal reproducible case, I changed the variable from an argument into a property, but the issue is the same.

```kotlin
class Foo {
    val bar: Bar? = null
}

class Bar

fun interface FooBarSelector {
    fun select(foo: Foo): Bar?
}

class KotlinClass() {
    val selector: FooBarSelector = Foo::bar
}
```

This doesn't compile, `Foo::bar` is underlined and the error is

```
Type mismatch.
Required: FooBarSelector
Found: KProperty1<Foo, Bar?>
```

I tried to look this up, found similar questions about SAM conversions, but they were a bit different and I don't think any of them referred specifically to property getters.

I found that the issue can be solved by doing one of the following:

1. Remove the explicit type, or replace it with the suggested `KProperty1`. Not an option, I want to preserve my type.
2. Replace the method reference with `FooBarSelector { it.bar }`. Far from ideal, but better than the first option.

Why does this happen and are there any other options? I am new to Kotlin, but not Java.

Kotlin version used is 1.7.20

**EDIT:**

Here's my original goal: accept a `FooBarSelector` as an argument, and by default point it at a property getter:

```kotlin
fun doSomething(
    selector: FooBarSelector = Foo::bar //doesn't compile
) {
}
```

Comment: I really don't understand what you are expecting here. Variable `selector` can't be of type `FooBarSelector` when you are not assigning a `FooBarSelector` to it and instead are assigning a function reference from `FooBarSelector`. And this kind of function references type is `KProperty<T,K>` in Kotlin. So what's the problem here?

Comment: @Tarmo apparently, the OP expects a feature like in Java, where `FooBarSelector selector = Foo::bar;` would work

Comment: Yeah, I come from Java and expected similar behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code with the lambda is fine, but you may prefer this syntax for the same thing:

```
class KotlinClass() {
    val selector = FooBarSelector(Foo::bar)
}
```

Explanation:

Kotlin function references are more explicit about types than in Java, because function references are a first-class object type. When you want to use a function reference as a functional interface instance, you must convert it. This can be done automatically by the compiler using SAM conversion.

SAM conversion only works when passing a function reference as an argument to a function that has a parameter with a functional interface type. So, it doesn't directly work when assigning to a property.

But Kotlin implicitly provides higher order functions for functional interfaces that allow you to pass a function reference that will convert it into an interface instance. The implicit function is named after the interface, so it looks like a constructor call.

In the above code, the implicit functional interface "constructor" is `inline`, so there is no intermediate functional object allocated in the compiled code. This compiles to the same thing you would get in Java with a direct method reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added an example of passing a function reference to a method and assigning a default value for it if it's not provided (my original use case). Is this not the same? Why is there no SAM conversion in this case?

Comment: To me, it's not the same. Each individual default parameter initializer is not a function call. Should they have supported it? Possibly, and maybe it's just an oversight. Before Kotlin 1.6, there was no `fun interface` and SAM conversions could only be used for Java interfaces. You were expected to always prefer function types instead of interfaces, and functional interfaces were the ugly Java cousin. They eventually realized there were some shortcomings with that restriction, but perhaps all the use cases aren't fully realized yet. Or there could be some syntax issue it would cause.

Comment: In general, it's still recommended that you should prefer using function types instead of functional interfaces, except for specific uses. Read here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/fun-interfaces.html#functional-interfaces-vs-type-aliases Basically, it's only if you need the other features of the interface (additional properties and functions with default implementations, or extension functions).

Comment: I also just found out that Kotlin's native function types always perform boxing since they employ generics. So that's another thing to keep in mind. Functional interfaces allow you to force primitive types as arguments. Waiting for valhalla to release hopefully before year 2050.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you are expecting but consider this example:

```
class Foo(
  val bar: Bar
)

data class Bar(
  val value: String
)

interface FooBarSelector {
  fun select(foo: Foo): Bar {
    return foo.bar
  }
}

class FooBarCustomSelector: FooBarSelector {
  override fun select(foo: Foo): Bar {
    return Bar("I don't care about which Foo was passed. I'll return my own Bar")
  }
}

class KotlinClass(val selector: (Foo) -> Bar = Foo::bar)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val kotlinClassWithDefaultSelector = KotlinClass()
  val kotlinClassWithCustomSelector = KotlinClass(FooBarCustomSelector()::select)
  val foo = Foo(Bar("Bar1"))
  println("kotlinClassWithDefaultSelector: ${kotlinClassWithDefaultSelector.selector(foo)}")
  println("kotlinClassWithCustomSelector: ${kotlinClassWithCustomSelector.selector(foo)}")
}
```

This would print:

```
kotlinClassWithDefaultSelector: Bar(value=Bar1)
kotlinClassWithCustomSelector: Bar(value=I don't care about which Foo was passed. I'll return my own Bar)
```